# How to stop plotting when newly iterated scatter point is plotted on aleardy plotted scatter point?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, logic, scatter-plot

I am writing a code where I want the scatter plot to stop as soon as my code tries to plot a scatter point on an already existing scatter point.

This is the code I wrote that works for a divisor of 360,

```
r = 2
pi = np.pi
i = 0
theta = 10
for i in range(100):
    x = r*np.cos(theta +i*theta )
    y = r*np.sin(theta +i*theta )
    plt.scatter(x,y, label = i+1)
    if (theta +i*theta == 360):
        print(i)
        break
```

when theta = 10, the plotting process stops at i = 35

[image: Plot_1]

but rather than having my if condition as "stop code when theta is equal to 360", I need a code when code stops when a scatter point overlaps another, since this condition does not work for other integers.

Comment: Hi, I want to make sure that if x = r\*np.cos(theta +i\*theta ) and y = r\*np.sin(theta +i\*theta ) should be written as   x = r\*np.cos(np.deg2rad(theta +i\*theta )) and  y = r\*np.sin(np.deg2rad(theta +i\*theta )) ?

Comment: I am not really sure. Since my if statement is theta<360, then theta should be in degree. I assumed that the default angle unit is degree in python. Is it not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following code

```
x = r*np.cos(theta +i*theta ) 
y = r*np.sin(theta +i*theta )
```

should be written as

```
x = r*np.cos(np.deg2rad(theta +i*theta )) 
y = r*np.sin(np.deg2rad(theta +i*theta ))
```

then you can change **theta** to any other value when using  **if (theta +i*theta == 360)** to avoid scatters overlapping.

In the following code, I changed **theta** from 10 to 5, and used red text to show the overlapping points.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
r = 2
pi = np.pi
i = 0
theta = 5
nloop = 100

for i in range(nloop):
#     x = r*np.cos(theta +i*theta )
#     y = r*np.sin(theta +i*theta )
    x = r*np.cos(np.deg2rad(theta +i*theta ))
    y = r*np.sin(np.deg2rad(theta +i*theta ))
    plt.scatter(x,y, label = i+1)
    if (theta +i*theta == 360):
        break


ax = plt.gca()
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(12,12)
ax.set_aspect(1) 
#### the code below only for debug
for i in range(nloop):
    x = r*np.cos(np.deg2rad(theta +i*theta ))
    y = r*np.sin(np.deg2rad(theta +i*theta ))
    
    if (theta +i*theta >= 360+theta):
        ax.text(x,y, f'{i}',ha="right",fontsize=12,color='r')
    else:
        ax.text(x,y ,f'{i}',ha="left",fontsize=12)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Li Yupeng. Your code helped me to reach my final goal. What I really want is for the code to stop plotting as soon as point 72 is over point 0. Say for theta = 1.7, it would take 1.7 periods so that one point is over another one. Here it is not necessary that it completes 360 degrees so if the statement does not work for all of it. Although I was able to for an algorithm that does the job I was just curious if there was any easy way to do that.